# How to verify for a specific type using Chai expect() in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, mocha.js, chai, typescript-generics

I've tried looking for an answer in previous posts, but I havnt found one so here it is:

I am currently trying to test the returned type of an Object instance property value using expect() from Chai in Typescript. So far, I've tried this:

```
/* My type file */

export type customType = "one" | "two" | "three";
export default customType;

/* My test file */

import customType from '{path_to_customType}'; // 'customType' is declared but its value is never read.

const newObject = new Object({property1: value1}) //note: value1 is of type customType

describe("Class1 test", () => {
    it('my tests', () => {
        expect(newObject).to.have.property("property1").to.equal("value1"); //so far, this one works fine
        expect(newObject).to.be.a('customType'); // not working
        expect(newObject).to.be.an('customType'); // not working
        expect(newObject).to.be.a(customType); // not working
        expect(newObject).to.be.an(customType); // not working
        expect(typeof newObject.getProperty1()).to.equal('customType'); // not working
        expect(newObject).to.be.an.instanceof(customType); // not working
        expect(newObject).to.be.an.instanceof('customType'); // not working
        assert.typeOf(newObject.getProperty1(), 'customType'); // not working
        assert.typeOf(newObject.getProperty1(), customType); // not working
    });
});
```

As you can see, `value1` is supposed to be of type `customType` but it gives me an error since `customType` is never read.
How can I verify if my value is of a specific custom type?

**Note: in my Object definition, the property `property1` is specified of type `customType`

***UPDATE** I just noticed the returned type of `value1` is 'string' as if the type is only an alias... How can I test that then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript's type system is purely a compile-time feature. Running code doesn't have types. You can use `typeof` to test whether values are boolean, number, string, object, etc., and you can also test whether an Object is an instance of a class.

Your `customType`, however, simply isn't something that can be checked at runtime. Once the code has been converted into JavaScript in order to run, `customType` is just a string like any other string.

Comment: I am mind blown. Thanks ! haha